# Unable to start robot state publisher due to missing library

Tags: robot-state-publisher, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to launch robot_state_publisher with the launch file:

```
<launch>
    <arg name="model" default="$(find mybot_description)/urdf/mybot.urdf.xacro"/>
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(arg model)" />
    <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" />
</launch>
```

it dies with the error:

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/robot_state_publisher/state_publisher: error while loading shared libraries: librobot_state_publisher_solver.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Obviously, I have the ros-kinetc-robot-state-publisher package installed. Why is it throwing this error? Searching apt-cache finds nothing providing that .so file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245361/unable-to-start-robot-state-publisher-due-to-missing-library/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2016-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I confirmed the .so file is located in `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/librobot_state_publisher_solver.so`. The problem was I was running roslaunch from the wrong directory, and I hadn't sourced my shell with the appropriate ROS environment variables.

---

Originally posted by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) with karma: 940 on 2018-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0